# How to test no extra fields is delared in subclass which means all fields are inherited from the super class?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Here is the problem. I got a abstract class Action and his subclass RegularAction. I have to write a test class to test there is no extra fileds is declared in class RegularAction, all fields is  inherited from Action abstract class.

The test need return as a True or false.

```
public abstract class Action {
  private String description;

  public Action(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public abstract boolean occursOn(int year,int month,int day);

  public String toString() {
    return description;
  }
}

public class RegularAction extends Action {
  public RegularAction(String description) {
    super(description);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day) {


    return true;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: You would have to use reflection. Also, the `occursOn()` implementation makes no sense.

Comment: The assignment required that to use abstract class and its subclass to solve